# Ionic 3 Android apk size with --prod

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3, sqlcipher

I was trying to analyse the reasons why the apk generated by my Ionic project for Android was very large (~18.6 MB). Details of the package versions used follow:

**cli packages:** (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

**global packages:**

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

**local packages:**

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.4.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

**System:**

```
Node : v9.4.0
npm  : 5.8.0 
OS   : Linux 4.4
```

When I analysed the apk using Android Studio, I was surprised to note that the lib folder contributed to ~ 82% of the total apk size (14.7 MB out of 18.6 MB). Details are provided below:

**Raw APK file size**          18.6 MB

**lib**                        14.7 MB

**x86**                       3.8 MB

```
libsqlcipher.so         1.9 MB
libSecurityServices.so  1.4 MB     
libsr_agent_o.so        0.5 MB
libtbxml.so             6.0 KB
```

**x86_64**                    3.2 MB

```
libsqlcipher.so         1.7 MB
libSecurityServices.so  1.5 MB     
libsr_agent_o.so        1.2 KB
libtbxml.so             5.5 KB
```

**arm64-v8a**                 3.0 MB

```
libsqlcipher.so         1.7 MB
libSecurityServices.so  1.3 MB     
libsr_agent_o.so        1.0 KB
libtbxml.so             5.3 KB
```

**armeabi-v7a**               2.4 MB

```
libsqlcipher.so         1.2 MB
libSecurityServices.so  1.2 MB     
libsr_agent_o.so        4.8 KB
libtbxml.so             5.3 KB
```

**armeabi**                   2.4 MB

```
libsqlcipher.so         1.3 MB
libSecurityServices.so  1.1 MB     
libsr_agent_o.so        5.1 KB
libtbxml.so             8.5 KB
```

classes.dex                 1.6 MB

**assets**                      1.3 MB

**res**                         0.4 MB

The libSecurityServices.so is used by com-intel-security-cordova-plugin and the libsqlcipher.so is used by cordova-sqlcipher-adapter plugin.

Do I need to have all the target platforms listed above? I am planning to target only phones supporting API levels between 16 - 25. I am not targeting Android TV or Android Wear. Even knocking off a couple of platform folders in the lib directory can save me atleast a couple of MB in apk size.